# Find probability and conditional probability, given percentages of three groups

Tags: probability

> In a coorporation there are 3% absence due to sickness each day. 60% of those are men. 30% of the cooporations employees are women. So,
>
> M = the employee are  male
>   F = the employee are female
>   S = employee is home due to sickness.
>
> My task is to find P(M) and P(S|M).

I've tried to look around for some examples to apply to this problem but I can't manage to find one.

I need a hint or something to get started. I'm very rusty in probability-calculation.

Comment: Do you recall Bayes' Theorem?
What does the text tell us about $P(F)$ and therefore consequently about $P(M)$?

Comment: Use the definition of conditional probability: $\Pr(S\mid M)=\frac{\Pr(S\cap M)}{\Pr(M)}$.

Comment: Also keep into account rule of differences; if all employees are either male or female, how can you derive $P(M)$ from $P(F)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text gives us the following information:

$P(S) = 0.03, P(M|S) = 0.6, P(F) = 0.3$

> **Theorem**(Bayes' Theorem):
>   $P(S|M) = \frac{P(S)P(M|S)}{P(M)}$

We can calculate $P(M) = 1 - P(F) = 0.7$ because all employees are either male or female.
Then Bayes' Theorem gives us:

$P(S|M) = 0.0257...$

Comment: Thank you for a good answer! Need this for my further problems! :)